# Disabling JComboBox and retaining original item list

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

My action listener on a JComboBox invokes a thread. I would like the component to be disabled until the thread completes.

I have tried calling seEnabled(false) when the thread start and setEnabled(true) when it completes. Unfortunately setEnabled(false) clears the combo box list as well.

Is there a way of disabling the component but retain the original list?

Comment: What do you mean by "clears the list"? Removing all elements of the list or just closing (not showing) the list? I made some tests and, as expected, `setEnabled` does not remove the elements from the list... maybe you could include some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setEnabled(false) definitely doesn't clear the contents of the combo box. Something else must be going on.

Posting your code might help.